# Interpretation of Boolean - Find Kth Largest element in unsorted array

Tags: python, algorithm

I tried to solve the Leetcode problem mentioned in the title (I'm not asking for an optimal answer, but I'm looking for an explanation for a phenomenon).

This is my algorithm:

```
def findKthLargest(nums, k) :
    def findrealposition(index,nums):
        ind = index
        index1 = index + 1
        while index1 < len(nums) :
            if nums[ind] < nums[index1] : 

                index1 += 1
            else : 
                nums[ind], nums[index1] = nums[index1], nums[ind]
                ind += 1
                index1 += 1

        return ind, nums
    index = 0
    while findrealposition(index,nums)[0] != len(nums)-k : 

        if findrealposition(index,nums)[0] < len(nums)-k : 
            print('less')
            index, nums = 0, findrealposition(index,nums)[1]
        else : 
            print('more')
            index, nums = findrealposition(index,nums)
    return nums[len(nums)-k]
```

The problem is the following: run the algorithm with[4,3,1] as a list, and 1 as a position, the "findrealposition" function with input 0 (so the position of 4 with a sorted list) gives 2 as an output (and the list as a second position). That's a good thing. But when I print (findrealposition(0,nums)[0] < 2), then the output is... True. Thus, wy while loop is an infinite loop.

I suppose there is a subtlety in Python that I don't know, which makes me fail.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the "Error in Boolean"? It just sounds like a number is not what you think it is, not that somehow or other `<` is misfiring on integers for some sublte Python-specific reason.

Comment: Yes, misunderstanding of the answer in Boolean would be a more appropriate title.

Comment: So, my question would be : why as the output is 2, (and I printed it) the Boolean (output < 2) gives me "True" ?

Comment: You are mistaken. If `output = 2` then `output < 2` is False. Either you are mistaken about the value on the left of `<` or you are mistaken about the value on the right.

Comment: I can make a capture of my screen if you want. But I ensure you that
1) I print findrealposition(0,nums)[0] -> 2
2) I print len(nums)-1 -> 2
3) I print (findrealposition(0,nums)[0] < len(nums)-1 -> True

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] which others can run which 1) prints the value of an int variable `2` and 2) evaluates the comparison of that variable and 2 to be `True`.

Comment: I am not sure to understand, but I use my algorithm "findrealposition" with in input 0 and nums = [4,3,1]
And I made (findrealposition(0,[4,3,1] < 2)

Comment: @G.Hanna the boolean comparison is correct, the first output of your function is  `ind = 3` then `ind =2` and then it prints `more`

Comment: But only inside my principal algorithm.

Comment: The problem is that you are *mutating* your list, changing the value of `findrealposition` between the print and the comparison. That mutation causes the new return value to be `1`. To see this, print `indrealposition(0,nums)` twice in a row.

Comment: So why, when I print it, it gives me as output the value "2" ?

Comment: @G.Hanna I didn't understand about the principal algorithm part. I think the issue you are facing is that lists are passed by reference and you need to make a deep copy of the list

Comment: It gives you `2` because that is the output *given the state of `nums` when you pass it*. But -- the next time you call it, the state of `nums` is not the same, so the output isn't the same. You can't reason about a mutating object as if it were constant.

Comment: @G.Hanna how are you printing the values ?

Comment: @Albin Paul I didn't want to use copy, I tried to get a solution with a minimum of lost of memory
@ J. Coleman, yes, you are right. I used the print function to try to see where was the problem, but maybe I made some mistake before, and so the print function couldn't permit me of capture the first problem.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: @ Albin Paul : just using the print function (I didn't write it on the main post, in order to have a more readable code.

Comment: @G.Hanna print the ind value inside the `findrealposition` function and then analyze you will understand. Dont do `print(findrealposition(index,nums)[0])`

Comment: @Albin Paul : Thank you for the advice ! =)

Comment: @JohnColeman is right: your algorithm changes the state of the list, so you get different results if you call it on the same list multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Booleans.

It is quite possible for `f(nums) == 2` to be true and then for `f(nums) < 2` to be true immediately afterwards, for some function `f`, without this being a paradox or indicating a fundamental flaw in the language. The reason is simply that `f(nums)` can return 2 and then calling `f(nums)` again can return 1. It should surprise nobody that `2 == 2` and `1 < 2` are both true.

Your function indeed behaves this way:

```py
>>> nums = [4, 3, 1]
>>> findrealposition(0, nums)
(2, [3, 1, 4])
>>> findrealposition(0, nums)
(1, [1, 3, 4])
```

This function gives different outputs each time because you gave it different inputs. The `findrealposition` function changes the order of the elements of `nums`, so when you call it the second time, they are in a different order and the function computes a different output.